# Finding the smallest indices of a pandas datafrmae where column value equality holds

Tags: pandas, indexing, python-3.8

```
data = """
id,name
100,A
100,B
101,C
101,D
101,pp;
212,E
212,F
215,ds
215,G
215,trtr
219, dsds
219, sas
219, dasa
300,Endüstrisi`
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
df = pd.concat([df]*5)
```

I have the above dataframe and I am given a numpy array of ids as `ids = np.array([100,212,219])`

I want to get the indices of the original dataframe where the `ids` first appears in `df`

I thought of using isin function with indxmin, but unfortunately, it didn't work.

My output should be `np.array([0,5,10])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `drop_duplicates`

```
s = df.drop_duplicates('id')
out = s[s['id'].isin(ids)].index.values
Out[168]: array([ 0,  5, 10], dtype=int64)
```